# Portable bourne shell script without using functions of modern shells as bash, ksh, zsh etc

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

First of all I want thank all of you who will help me solve this. I have an exam tomorrow and I have to prepare this script for the exam. I am really new to linux and those bourne shell script.

My project should be a portable bourne shell script which scans a directory for the following files: `header.txt`, `footer.txt` and `content.txt`. The content of the files should be read but ignoring the lines starting with `#` and this content should be used for generating an HTML page with the following header, footer and content. This files can contain any text and/or HTML code but the cannot contain head and body tags. When scanning the directory the script have to compare the date of the last change of the files (`header.txt`, `footer.txt` and `content.txt`) with the date of the last change of the HTML page (if you have one already) and if the date of the last edit on the files is newer than the one on the HTML page the script should generate a new HTML page with the latest content.

Guys thank you very much as this is very important for me. Please help me getting this done.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Guys please don't vote against my question... Please help me solve this or just give me resources from where I can find examples or info on how to do it. Please it's very important...

Comment: If you want to find someone to do your exams for you, try freelancer.com or similar.

Comment: No mate, I want to do it myself I am just stuck with the deadline. I just want the "start kick" just some resources some direction on what to read and what will help me to write this script.

Comment: ...but that's is not what StackOverflow is for. We're here to build a reusable knowledge base of specific technical questions paired with answers. This is not a specific, reusable question (unless someone else happens to be doing the same exam).

Comment: I already did it myself with the things that user3374657 answered here and with a bit of googling. I know that is not right to post questions like this one but I really had to do it. Here is 3 am and I am still in front of the PC and the exam is at 9 am. Thank you for the opportunity to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove lines beginning with `#` try this:

```
grep -v "^#" file
```

To remove lines that may contain spaces (or blank characters) before a `#`:

```
grep -v "^[[:blank:]]*#" file
```

Comment: I am starting the file with #! /bin/sh this is correct right? I found that I can use the find function to find the files.

that's what I wrote:

find /home/berchev/linux -iname 'header.txt'
find /home/berchev/linux -iname 'footer.txt'
find /home/berchev/linux -iname 'content.txt'

how do I read the content of those files?

Comment: I think that you may read the file well without ***find*** it, for get the contents of the file try `cat /home/berchev/FILE.txt` or, better `cat ~/linux/FILE.txt`, with the second command is portable to any linux installation, even if the user name is not `berchev`, if do you want to save file contents in a variable try this `MYVAR=$(cat ~/linux/FILE.txt)` and yes, `#!/bin/sh`is the correct entry if do you want to make it portable.

Comment: thanks, i have to find the files because it is required that the script scan the directory and then uses the content of the files, so I have to scan the directory for those files and read them and then assign them to variables so I can use the variables for the HTML page. I think i have to use if for this but how to configure it if those files are present in the directory to assign their content to a variable

Comment: For read the file and remove commented lines, all in one command, try this: `MYVAR=$(grep -v "^[[:blank:]]*#" ~/linux/FILE.txt)`, in this example, you can put indented comments (with spaces and tabs before the `#`)

Comment: yes that's exactly what I used, no this is my script

#! /bin/sh

if [ -e ~/linux/header.txt ]
then
HEADER=$(grep -v "^[[:blank:]]*#" ~/linux/header.txt)
echo $HEADER
else
echo "Header file not found"
fi

if [ -e ~/linux/content.txt ]
then
CONTENT=$(grep -v "^[[:blank:]]*#" ~/linux/content.txt)
echo $CONTENT
else
echo "Content file not found"
fi

if [ -e ~/linux/footer.txt ]
then
FOOTER=$(grep -v "^[[:blank:]]*#" ~/linux/footer.txt)
echo $FOOTER
else
echo "Footer file not found"
fi

How can I use this variables to generate an html page with head and body tags already placed there?

Comment: Try `echo "<HTML>"` `echo "<HEAD>"` `echo $HEADER` `echo "</HEAD>"` `echo "<BODY>"` `echo $CONTENT` `echo $FOOTER` `echo "</BODY"` `echo "</HTML>"`

Comment: The exam is successfully passed? :-)

Comment: Hi yep, the exam is passed here the grades are from 2 to 6 the lowest one is 2 and the best one is 6 i got 5 :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great, I'm happy to be able to help you, any questions you have can I ask it in this community, I'm sure someone answers them (might even be me)